# Finding Existence of This Limit

Tags: limits

I've been trying to find
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{3x^3 - 6xy}{x-9.3\sqrt{y}}.$$
I tried to first try to find counterexamples to the existence of this limit, but I kept running into issues when studying the limit on the $x = y$ curve, which simplifies to $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{3x^{5/2} - 6x^{3/2}}{\sqrt{x}-9.3} = 0,$ and finding functions to bound via the squeeze theorem seems tough. That being said, I am having issues moving from here. Is it possible that there could be some trick to the fraction that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist. If you go along the line $y=(x/9.3)^2$, the denominator is zero, while the numerator is 
$$
3x^3-6x^3/9.3=(3-6/9.3)x^3,
$$
nonzero for any $x\ne0$.